# Why does summarize function don't get an error?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

We all know that we can compute any summary that operates on vectors and returns a single value in R base.
I want to ask that why I don't get an error when I attempt to use quantile which returns more than one value function inside of summarize?

```
heights %>%
    filter(sex == "Male") %>%
    summarize(range = quantile(height, c(0, 0.5, 1)))
```

result is not an error:

```
     range
1 50.00000
2 69.00000
3 82.67717
```

Comment: `dplyr 1.0.0` permits `summarize()` to return vectors of length > 1 see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/.

Comment: From the examples of `summarise`'s [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#examples), `dplyr 1.0.0` allows to summarise to more than one value

Comment: I got it, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just making my comment and @27ϕ9's an answer.*

As of `dplyr` version `1.0.0`, `summarise` allows to return outputs containing more than one value.

Example:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(qs = quantile(disp, c(0.25, 0.75)), prob = c(0.25, 0.75))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#     cyl    qs  prob
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  78.8  0.25
# 2     4 121.   0.75
# 3     6 160    0.25
# 4     6 196.   0.75
# 5     8 302.   0.25
# 6     8 390    0.75
```

See the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#examples) for more examples.